# LaTeX align word characters to the right

Tags: pdf, latex, alignment

I made a latex document with a line next to the margin

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[left=0.95in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{background}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgColor{black}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgHshift{0pt}
\SetBgVshift{0mm}

\SetBgContents{
\hspace{1in}           
\rule{1pt}{\paperheight} % right first line
\rule[0.75in]{6.5in}{1pt} % bottom line
\rule{1pt}{\paperheight}
}

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{3.0in}

\begin{document}

\reversemarginpar{\vspace{1em}

   \begin{spacing}{1.6} %space vertical between numbers
     \noindent  Sam \\  Rams\\  Tamim \\  Smartcoi \\  9d5 \\  lousy99\\  

\end{spacing}}
\end{document}
```

How do I get the characters on the words to align right and end at the line? Currently it renders like this:[image]

I am trying to get the end of the words to line up with the line. I tried `\begin{flushright}` but it moved everything out of place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is to use a tabular:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,top=1in,right=0.5in,bottom=0.75in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagenumbering{gobble}


\begin{document}

\reversemarginpar%
\marginpar{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
Sam \\  
Rams\\  
Tamim \\  
Smartcoi \\  
9d5 \\  
lousy99\\
\end{tabular}%  
}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]